# How do i know the age of person using groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset that knows why a patient didn't meet up with a doctor's appointment. There are many conditions. However, we want to know which affects more.

The dependent variable was initially defined with "YES" and "NO" so I had to redefine as "1" and "0":

```
df.No_Show[df['No_Show'] == 'Yes'] = '1'
df.No_Show[df['No_Show'] == 'No'] = '0'
df['No_Show'] = pd.to_numeric(df['No_Show'])
```

again, redefined as:

```
showed = df.No_Show == 1
No_show = df.No_Show == 0
```

while trying to know the mean of those who went for appointment by age, using

```
df.groupby('Age')[showed].mean()
```

I got an error.

Comment: Try to provide a complete minimal reproducible example. What is the error you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `showed` is just a series with booleans. You probably wanted to do `df.loc[showed].mean()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df[showed].groupby('Age').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "No_Show": np.array(np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)),
        "Age": np.random.randint(1, 100, 100),
    }
)
df.groupby("Age")["No_Show"].mean()

Age
1     0.666667
2     1.000000
3     0.000000
4     1.000000
6     1.000000
        ...   
92    1.000000
94    0.500000
95    1.000000
96    0.000000
98    0.500000
Name: No_Show, Length: 63, dtype: float64


df.groupby("No_Show")["Age"].mean()


No_Show
0    53.833333
1    47.346154
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

## Importing

`import pandas as pd`

## Grouping by specific values

```
df.loc[lambda x: x['showed'] == 'yes'].groupby('showed')['age'].mean()
```